# How do I code this one in vb6?

Tags: vb6

How do I get the next value in an array to used in condition in a looping.

```
dim x(10) as integer
dim d1,d2 as integer

for i = 0 to 10 

 d1 = x(1) 'first value in an array e.g. is 10
 d2 = x(2) 'second value in an array e.g. is 20

 if (d2-d1) > 1 then
     Msgbox "Item Count"
 else 
     msgbox "Item Deleted"
 end if

next i
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `SQL`?

Comment: im sorry for tagging sql.,im using sql in my database., although it was not part of the problem im asking.,

Comment: It would help us, help you if you tell us what you are trying to accomplish by this code. Are you searching for the maximum value in an array? There is better ways for that.

Comment: Normally You'd check at the top of the next iteration when you actually have the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you need to use **Step** key word with for loop as below:

```
Dim x(10) As Integer
Dim d1, d2 As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 8 Step 2

 d1 = x(i + 1) 'first value in an array e.g. is 10
 d2 = x(i + 2) 'second value in an array e.g. is 20

 If (d2 - d1) > 1 Then
     MsgBox "Item Count"
 Else
     MsgBox "Item Deleted"
  End If

Next i
```

Comment: what if he wants to test sequentially? not every pair of numbers, also you are ignoring the 0 index of the array, try (i) and (i+1) instead

Comment: I just want to condition every loop the value of the second array to be deducted on first array,.supposed on the first loop the value of 1st array is 10.,then i want to get the the value of the second array on the second loop ,suppose it's 20. then it is done sequentially through out the loop..